# Connected component labeling in Emgu / Opencv

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I've been look ing for a method for connected component labeling in Emgu (c# wrapper for OpenCV). I've failed to find a direct method for such a basic CV strategy. However, I did come across many suggestions for doing it using FindContours and DrawContours but without code examples. So I had a go at it and it seems to work okay.

I'm dropping it here for two reasons.

1. So people searching for it can find a code example.
2. More importantly, i'm wondering if there are suggestions for optimization and improvements of this function. E.g. is the chain approximation method for FindContours efficient/appropriate?

```cs
    public static Image<Gray, byte> LabelConnectedComponents(this Image<Gray, byte> binary, int startLabel)
    {
        Contour<Point> contours = binary.FindContours(
            CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, 
            RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_CCOMP);

        int count = startLabel;
        for (Contour<Point> cont = contours;
                    cont != null;
                    cont = cont.HNext)
        {
            CvInvoke.cvDrawContours(
            binary,
            cont,
            new MCvScalar(count),
            new MCvScalar(0),
            2,
            -1,
            LINE_TYPE.FOUR_CONNECTED,
            new Point(0, 0));
            ++count;
        }
        return binary;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following:

```
   connected component labeling (AForge / Accord.NET ?)
   (although for many cases you will find it almost the same for the function that you wrote, give it a try to verify the results)
```

After this step you will probably find more regions that are close together and that belong to the same person.
Than you can use:
       implement or search for implementation of hierarhical aglomerative clustering (HCA)
to combine close region.

P.S.:
 is the chain approximation method for FindContours efficient/appropriate

if you are using NO_APPROX no approximations of chain code will be used. By using this you can get non-smoothed edges (with many small hills and valleys) but if that does not bother you than this parameter value is fine.